# Replacing / Mocking all new instances of class

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, python-mock

I have the following situation.

```
class Class1():
    def __init__(self, param1):
        self.param = param1
    def my_func_1(self):
        return "Hello " + self.param1

class Class2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.instance_of_class_1 = Class1('Real')

    def do_it(self):
        return self.instance_of_class_1.my_func_1()

class Class3():
    def __init__(self):
        self.instace_of_class_2 = Class2()

    def do_it(self):
        return self.instace_of_class_2.do_it()
```

I have a test that initiates a `Class3` object but I want to mock the new  instance of `Class1` inside the constructor of `Class2`. This is what i did so far:

```
def test_my_classes():
    with patch('my.module.Class1') as class_1_mock:
        class_1_mock.my_func_1.return_value = "Hello Fake"
        class_3 = Class3()
        assert class_3.do_it() == 'Hello Fake' #fails
```

I'm guessing because `Class1` constructor takes params - its not a simple patch.

Comment: Why does `Class2.do_it()` use `print`? You can't test any return values without `return` *statements*.

Comment: mistake in the code - will fix. assume it returns the string.

Answer (score 0):

You are mocking `Class1` correctly, but forgot to take into account it is *called* to produce an instance. The `my_func_1` would be looked up on the call result (on the instance):

```
def test_my_classes():
    with patch('my.module.Class1') as class_1_mock:
        class_1_mock.return_value.my_func_1.return_value = "Hello Fake"
```

Mock doesn't care that you produced an instance or that `my_func_1` is a bound method, only that you call `Class1`.

You can then make assertions if the class was called with the correct parameters, if you so desire:

```
class_1_mock.assert_called_once_with('Real')
```

Demo:

```
>>> from mock import patch
>>> class Class1():
...     def __init__(self, param1):
...         self.param = param1
...     def my_func_1(self):
...         return "Hello " + self.param1
...
>>> class Class2():
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.instance_of_class_1 = Class1('Real')
...     def do_it(self):
...         return self.instance_of_class_1.my_func_1()
...
>>> class Class3():
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.instace_of_class_2 = Class2()
...     def do_it(self):
...         return self.instace_of_class_2.do_it()
...
>>> with patch('__main__.Class1') as class_1_mock:
...     class_1_mock.return_value.my_func_1.return_value = "Hello Fake"
...     class_3 = Class3()
...     print class_3.do_it() == 'Hello Fake'
...
True
>>> class_1_mock.mock_calls
[call('Real'), call().my_func_1()]
```

I included `class_1_mock.mock_calls` to show that `call().my_func_1()` is included; that's the `Class1('Real')` instance being used to provide the `my_func_1()` method call.

Comment: When i debug the test and get to the line of initialization of Class1 then i see its of type `my.module.Class1` and not `MagicMock` - This is not the wanted affect.

Comment: @MrT.: are you certain you [patched the right location](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) then?

Comment: OK - now i understand my problem. I used the module where the class was defined and not where the class was used! Thanks :)